# Process 2 Ethereum Transactions with single Transaction

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I'm using third party SDK method and completing the transaction successfully. I'm trying to do the same function twice within a single ETH transaction. It's impossible with SDK method. I tried to deploy my own smart contract by using this function, but unfortunately, it doesn't have function's/smart contract's ABI. I have checked web3, ethers.js for any solution but could not find one.

```
const firstTx = await api.method(); // returns transactionHash
const secondTx = await api.method(); // returns transactionHash
```

Separately they work perfectly, but I need to process them with a single transaction. The second transaction depends on the first one, so it has to wait for the first function. Also, if any of the functions fail, both transactions should fail.

```
const singleTx = async() => {firstTX(); secondTx()} or {firstTx().then(()=>secondTx())} //returns single transactionHash
```

I need to implement it in a similar way. I'm stuck with that issue for more than 2 days.
Any recommendation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please contact the third party SDK provider for customer support on their product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id28), there's a `.send` function that returns a promise event. The event returns a few parameters, here you're looking for `confirmation`.

You could do something along the lines of:

```
myContract.methods.firstTx(args).send({from: wallet})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
    myContract.methods.secondTx(args)
})
```